# Edit the appearing Post Date in Ultimate Addons Elementor Posts with Events Skin (uael_post_event_date) in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have a big problem here. I need to display my post publish date in my blog section. (you can see it here, under the blog section in the homepage: https://netartsite.com.br/lamat/ ).

I'm using Elementor + Ultimate Addons for Wordpress (UAE), with the Posts Widget, with the Events skin. I have three blog posts there, one from March 22nd, and the other two from April 1st. The problem is that all three blog posts are displaying the date as April 1st, instead of the correct post publish date. (screenshot attached).

[screenshot from my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR36E.png)

I've already found in the plugin files the exact part that renders the date:

```
<div class="uael-post__datebox <?php echo wp_kses_post( $this->get_no_image_class() ); ?>">
            <div class="uael-post__date-wrap">
                <?php
                $date  = "<span class='uael-post__date-day'>";
                $date .= date_i18n( 'd', strtotime( get_the_date() ));
                $date .= '</span>';
                $date .= "<span class='uael-post__date-month'>";
                $date .= date_i18n( 'M', strtotime( get_the_date() ));
                $date .= '</span>';
                ?>
                <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'uael_post_event_date', $date, get_the_ID(), get_option( 'date_format' ), '', '' ) ); ?>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

Tried editing a lot in this part without success. After that, I found [This article](https://ultimateelementor.com/docs/filters-actions-for-posts-widget/#helps-modify-the-post-date-in-the-event-skin.) showing how could I add this code in my functions.php in order to achieve what I want, but again, without success.

So here am I guys, asking for your help: How could I change the displaying date to the actual post publishing date, and not only the last post publishing date?

Thank you a lot in advance!

**[EDIT]** I managed to get it working!!! \o/

Following the [previous article that I talked before](https://ultimateelementor.com/docs/filters-actions-for-posts-widget/#helps-modify-the-post-date-in-the-event-skin.), I had this piece of code to insert in my functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'uael_post_event_date', function( $date, $post_id, $date_format ) {
// Modify the date here
return $date;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Initially, I didn't understand well what I had to change in this file, as my knowledge in PHP is very basic. As I inserted the code, I had no changes in the frontend. So, I started researching about the Wordpress functions that could render the post publish date, and after trial and error (a lot, lol), I could get it to work using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'uael_post_event_date', function( $date, $post_id, $date_format ) {
$date = get_post_field( 'post_date', $post_id, $date_format );
$date_format = get_the_date('d M', $post_id);
// Modify the date here
return $date_format;
}, 10, 3 );
```

[Finally I have the publish date of each post, not the day only from the latest post!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmpqj.png)

I'm gonna leave this solution here, in case somebody has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the snippet you posted does not run in "the loop", so `get_the_date()` works on current page (or today date) instead of the specific post.

Is there an "id" reference somewhere in your code that you can use and pass to `get_the_date()` (as second parameter)?
Have you tried to change `get_the_date()` in this way?

> `get_the_date('', get_the_ID())`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! However, unfortunately it didn't work.. No changes at the final result... =/